# Send cluster or array of data generated by a machine programmed in LabVIEW, to Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, iot, labview

I've already tried to connect LabVIEW to Firebase, and it needs a json file. I added a knob to control the input and meter as an output. When I change the knob, let's say, to 5 for example, the meter also changes to 5.
Now the machine code is actually made, and it gives an array for the results of tests, and I want to send that array to Firebase.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Update: So i tried sending cluster using the unflatten to JSON function, using the same cluster in the example it did work, but when i use my own cluster it won't gives any results.

Comment: You mean _flatten_ to JSON. If this function doesn't give output, you might have datatypes in your input it can not handle, like time. Could you show what you did?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the api rest to your real time database in firebase

[api rest Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/)

then your labview code can use http post and http get to save and retrieve data.

the url have the following sintax
https://proyectID.firebaseio.com/Datacollection/somename.json

the somename.json does not mean a file, just mean the tag to be saved in your database, to encode any labview data use the function "Flatten to Json"
[sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY22D.png)